# Django sessions keeps returning 'NoneType' error

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I am currently using Django forms to have users enter information, which I then use Django sessions to call in other view functions in my views.py file. Currently my form is processed in the view function, 'search' and is called using sessions in latter view functions. However, when I enter data into my form and submit it, I get the error:

```
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Here is my code, thus far:

```
def search(request):
    t = request.session.get("tick")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = Search(data=request.POST)

        if search.is_valid():
            success = True
            ticker = search.cleaned_data['search']
            request.session["tick"] = ticker
        else:
            print search.errors
    else:
        search = Search()



def search_overview(request):
    result = {}

    context = RequestContext(request) 

    t = request.session.get("tick")

    sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+t).read()

    pbr = sourceCode.split('Price/Book (mrq):</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
    result['pbr'] = pbr

    return render_to_response('ui/search.html', {"result":result}, context)
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this, so that I can use sessions to store data touse in different view functions? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely, your issue is  `t = request.session.get("tick")` is returning a `None`

Comment: Yes, I tried , `print "t"` and got back `None`. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: If tick is returning none then ticker must not be assigned anything when you call "ticker = search.cleaned_data['search']", so I'd say look around there and see if anything turns up.

Answer (score 0):

In your `search_overview` function, `t` is getting set to `None`. Which cannot be concatenated with a string.

You could try this as a quick fix, but it doesn't solve the issue of `tick` not being in the session:

```
t = request.session.get('tick', '')
```

This returns the value for the `tick` key in `session` if it exists, otherwise it returns an empty string. Which can be concatenated to another string.